# How to write vector values to a file

Tags: c++, vector

I have a large vector.

The ways that I use multiply the run-time of the program hugely. The first is write all values to a string as they are calculated using `stringstreams` and later write the string to a file. The other method is to make a long string after the fact and write that to the file. However, both of these are very slow.

Is there a way to just write the vector's values to the text file immediately with line breaks?

Comment: "Is there a way to just write the vector's values to the text file immediately without line breaks?" - You need with or without line breaks??

Comment: It makes me happy to see my program finish what previously took it 3 hours in 5 minutes XD

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Using [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) and [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is the usual way to do this. Here is an example with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s using C++98 syntax (the question was asked pre-C++11):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> example;
    example.push_back("this");
    example.push_back("is");
    example.push_back("a");
    example.push_back("test");

    std::ofstream output_file("./example.txt");
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    std::copy(example.begin(), example.end(), output_iterator);
}
```

---

[Some years later]

A more modern implementation may look like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> example { "This", "is", "a", "test" };

    std::ofstream output_file("./example.txt");

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    std::copy(std::begin(example), std::end(example), output_iterator);
}
```

Comment: You should be careful using a string as the example. As the converse for loading a vector of strings is different (it is the only standard type where output/input will be different).

Comment: std::copy is actually in <algorithm>

Comment: A more modern implementation is:
`std::ranges::copy(example, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(output_file, "\n"));`

Comment: @Jean-Christophe: `std::ranges` was introduced in C++20, nearly a decade after this question was asked (and answered).

I'll leave my answer as is, as it helped the original poster and may still be useful to those working on heritage systems. I recommend that you provide a new answer for the modern era and newcomers to this page.

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you have C++11:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{ "one", "two", "three" };
    std::ofstream outFile("my_file.txt");
    // the important part
    for (const auto &e : v) outFile << e << "\n";
}
```

Comment: What if you wanted to write an entire row of vector of vector of float data into a binary file?

Comment: Just a note for myself: Don't forget to `.close();`.

Comment: ...or, use scope, i.e. `{ }`, since `std::ofstream` supports RAII concept.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe I have missed something, but what is wrong with:

```
std::ofstream f("somefile.txt");
for(vector<X>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
    f << *i << '\n';
}
```

That avoids having to do potentially quadratic string concatenation, which I assume is what's killing your run-time.

Comment: Sorry, what do v and X represent?

Comment: `v` is your containing vector. `X` is the type contained therein.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::copy](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy.html) and [std::ostream_iterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ostream_iterator.html).