# Save 2-dimensional vector to a text file

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

My problem is how to write a 2-dimensional vector to text file.

I already follow the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406356/writing-vector-values-to-a-file) and here is my code a bit changed to my need :

```
ofstream output_file("example.txt");
ostream_iterator<int> output_iterator(output_file, "\t");
for ( int i = 0 ; i < temp2d.size() ; i++ ) 
copy(temp2d.at(i).begin(), temp2d.at(i).end(), output_iterator);
```

my question is how to write the vector to the file row by row ?

This is what I want:

```
22 33 44
66 77 88
88 44 22
```

and so on.

This code writes all the elements of the vector in the same line.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of temp2d.

Comment: @steffen  vector<vector<int>> temp2d ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print out a new line character once you've copied the row, i.e. at the end of your for loop:

```
for(...)
{
  : // other code
  output_file << '\n';
}
```

Comment: And if you want to be a little bit safer and make sure the output is flushed to the file, use `std::endl` instead of plain newline.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I really wouldn't bother flushing on each new line, that will unnecessarily slow done the output, std:: streams flush themselves on when their lifetime ends, so there is nothing to gain unless you are reading AND writing from the same stream.

Answer (score 1):

I you have C++11 you can do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;

//do with v;

for(const auto& vt : v) {
     std::copy(vt.cbegin(), vt.cend(),
           std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
     std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Other wise typdefs are your friend.

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_v;
typedef std::vector<int_v> int_mat;
int_mat v;

for(int_mat::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
     std::copy(vt->begin(), vt->end(),
           std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
     std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's one way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;

  /* fill the vector ... */

  for(const auto& row : vec) {
    std::copy(row.cbegin(), row.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with `gcc --std=c++0x test_vector.cc`.