# How to store the data produced during a while loop?

Tags: c++, list, memory, printing, while-loop

I started C++ (as the 1st programming language I ever tried to learn) a few hours ago, and I am blocked on a very simple (I am sure of that) problem...

Basically I wanted to start with an algorithm that would give me, on a 2D surface of given height and width of integer values, a local "density value" for any point (defined by integers a & b).

The problem I have is, since I want to reuse the result, how to store the data that shows up when the program is started (the data that appears because of the command:

```
//print
cout<<D<<endl;
```

I really tried hard to find a solution without finding anything...
It could be stored in an external file, or in a kind of "buffer", any good solution would do the thing.

I just have to keep this data-list

Thanks!

here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include <vector> (the solution??)
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// constant values

float Da=0.1; //densities
float Db=0.5;
float Dc=1;
double Dd=1/3;

int l = 99;  //width & height
int h = 99;

float u = 1;  // UNIT


int main ()
{

    float a = 0;
    float b = 0; // Local variables



    while (a<l+1, b<h+1){

        //values for given a & b

        double DL = Da-Da*(b/h)+Dc*(b/h);
        double DR = Db-Db*(b/h)+Dd*(b/h);
        double D  = DL-DL*(a/l)+DR*(a/l);

        //print
        cout<<D<<endl;

        // next pixel & next line
        a++;
        if (a>l) {
            a = 0;
            b = b+u;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, `std::vector<double>` is good for this.  Declare a variable with a name, just like you've been doing, and then use the `push_back` member to add new data points to it.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I tried to use vector without success, I think I didn't get how to use it.

Comment: I didn't find a good example or tutorial on this topic, any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to store them in a list or something then vector is a great option as @Ben Voigt mentioned...

In your case:

```
std::vector<double> myVector;
.
.
.
.
double D  = DL-DL*(a/l)+DR*(a/l);

// Storing over the vector
myvector.push_back (D);
```

So now you can use the vector in any way you want to... Don't forget to uncomment ur line to include vectors... You can also use the "pop_back" method to remove something from it when needed to...

To load vector over file:
[Writing Vector Values to a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406356/writing-vector-values-to-a-file)

Good link for manipulating vectors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/8wt934f9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

If you need to know vectors: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Nice bunch of links. Little bit more working code in context of problem  and details about vector surely help.

Comment: Great, thanks, I got it! The 1st link was the good one for me

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com Alright that is good... Let us know if you need any more help and then u can close the post by accepting any of the answers you liked...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data you want to store showed up when the program ran, you could start the program by redirecting output to a file.

For example, in linux, unix, or an OS with a shell supporting data redirection:

myprogram > data.txt

You will then see the same data in a file "data.txt".

Comment: Would be an easy solution but I am searching for something more efficient. Also I am under windows... thanks anyway

Comment: You could use a database. Even if a structured `.txt` file can be considered as a database, a lot of efficient and powerful tools already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fstream to save your values to a file.

```
fstream output("densities");
```

Then replace `cout` with `output`.

This will cause your values to be written to a file named "densities" in the working directory of your application. This will always write the data to the same file, so be careful if you wanted to preserve the output between different runs.

When you later want to read that file in, you'll do something similar.

```
 fstream input("densities");
 vector<double> values;

 // ... inside your loop
 double value;
 input >> value;
 values.push_back(value);

 // ... somewhere else use the values
 // for example, get the 11th density value.
 double density = values[10];
```

Good luck!

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote: I added your line before the cout and replaced cout by output. Didn't work. Something's missing maybe? Thanks

Comment: What didn't work? It didn't compile, the output file was empty, or some other problem?

Comment: the output file didn't exist, I guess one line's missing or something. Also, normaly the program takes 2 sec. to terminate, became .2 sec. after modification

Comment: Welcome to debugging. You'll need to set a breakpoint at the start of your function and step through the code to see where it is failing. I'm sorry I don't have a Windows box handy to try it out here. One tip is to test `output.good()` after the spot you declare the stream.