# How to concurrently write to a file in c++(in other words, whats the fastest way to write to a file)

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, multiprocessing, c++14

I'm building a graphics engine, and I need to write te result image to a .bmp file. I'm storing the pixels in a `vector<Color>`. While also saving the width and the heigth of the image. Currently I'm writing the image as follows(I didn't write this code myself):

```
std::ostream &img::operator<<(std::ostream &out, EasyImage const &image) {

//temporaryily enable exceptions on output stream
enable_exceptions(out, std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
//declare some struct-vars we're going to need:
bmpfile_magic magic;
bmpfile_header file_header;
bmp_header header;
uint8_t padding[] =
        {0, 0, 0, 0};
//calculate the total size of the pixel data
unsigned int line_width = image.get_width() * 3; //3 bytes per pixel
unsigned int line_padding = 0;
if (line_width % 4 != 0) {
    line_padding = 4 - (line_width % 4);
}
//lines must be aligned to a multiple of 4 bytes
line_width += line_padding;
unsigned int pixel_size = image.get_height() * line_width;

//start filling the headers
magic.magic[0] = 'B';
magic.magic[1] = 'M';

file_header.file_size = to_little_endian(pixel_size + sizeof(file_header) + sizeof(header) + sizeof(magic));
file_header.bmp_offset = to_little_endian(sizeof(file_header) + sizeof(header) + sizeof(magic));
file_header.reserved_1 = 0;
file_header.reserved_2 = 0;
header.header_size = to_little_endian(sizeof(header));
header.width = to_little_endian(image.get_width());
header.height = to_little_endian(image.get_height());
header.nplanes = to_little_endian(1);
header.bits_per_pixel = to_little_endian(24);//3bytes or 24 bits per pixel
header.compress_type = 0; //no compression
header.pixel_size = pixel_size;
header.hres = to_little_endian(11811); //11811 pixels/meter or 300dpi
header.vres = to_little_endian(11811); //11811 pixels/meter or 300dpi
header.ncolors = 0; //no color palette
header.nimpcolors = 0;//no important colors

//okay that should be all the header stuff: let's write it to the stream
out.write((char *) &magic, sizeof(magic));
out.write((char *) &file_header, sizeof(file_header));
out.write((char *) &header, sizeof(header));

//okay let's write the pixels themselves:
//they are arranged left->right, bottom->top, b,g,r
// this is the main bottleneck
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < image.get_height(); i++) {
    //loop over all lines
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < image.get_width(); j++) {
        //loop over all pixels in a line
        //we cast &color to char*. since the color fields are ordered blue,green,red they should be written automatically
        //in the right order
        out.write((char *) &image(j, i), 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    }
    if (line_padding > 0)
        out.write((char *) padding, line_padding);
}
//okay we should be done
return out;
}
```

As you can see, the pixels are being written one by one. This is quite slow, I put some timers in my program, and found that the writing was my main bottleneck.

I tried to write entire (horizontal) lines, but I did not find how to do it(best I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6406411/10875953).

Secondly, I wanted to write to the file using multithreading(not sure if I need to use threading or processing). using openMP. But that means I need to specify which byte address to write to, I think, which I couldn't solve.

Latstly, I thought about immidiatly writing to the file whenever I drew an object, but then I had the same issue with writing to specific locations in the file.

So, my question is: what's the best(fastest) way to tackle this problem. (Compiling this for windows and linux)

Comment: If you look at the actual in-memory image data as an array of bytes, will they all be on the correct order if written to disk using the BMP header information? Then you can just write it in one go using a single `write` call. Be careful of things like line-padding though. as the current code handles that while your in-memory data probably don't have it. Perhaps write lines instead?

Comment: Multithreading is useful for computation, but does not help with disk I/O. The fastest way to write a file is sequentially and in large blocks, like 4 MB.

Comment: When I read the binary data of a generated .bmp file and print it with python I get the following:
´x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\.....´(image is mostly black) So I could try to just write it all at one(in blocks of 4 MB like rustyx said, or line by line. How could I write it line by line though?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is to just keep the code you currently have, but instead run the whole function in a background thread that doesn't impact your main event or rendering threads? If the image isn't used anywhere else, just pass a reference like your currently do, otherwise create an in-memory copy of it (passing the image object by value). Unless you need to save every frame that should be good enough.

Comment: If you're truly looking for the fastest write performance, you'll probably want to go with OS specific API calls that can bypass the normal caching done by the OS and interact directly with the disk hardware (but with additional complexity due to memory alignment restrictions).

Comment: Since this need to be compiled on both Windows and Linux, this is not an option.

Comment: Adding to what @rustyx said; Unless your file is stored on a RAID array, then all of its bytes will be stored on the same "drive." No matter how many CPUs your computer has, it's only going to have _one_ physical connection to the drive, and that connection is going to run at some fixed speed. Adding more threads might increase the speed with which your program computes the bytes, but it can't increase the speed of the interface to the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest method to write to a file is to use hardware assist.  Write your output to memory (a.k.a. buffer), then tell the hardware device to transfer from memory to the file (disk).

The next fastest method is to write all the data to a buffer then block write the data to the file.  If you want other tasks or threads to execute during your writing, then create a thread that writes the buffer to the file.

When writing to a file, the more data per transaction, the more efficient the write will be.  For example, 1 write of 1024 bytes is faster than 1024 writes of one byte.

The idea is to keep the data streaming.  Slowing down the transfer rate may be faster than a burst write, delay, burst write, delay, etc.

Remember that the disk is essentially a serial device (unless you have a special hard drive).  Bits are laid down on the platters using a bit stream.  Writing data in parallel will have adverse effects because the head will have to be moved between the parallel activities.

Remember that if you use more than one core, there will be more traffic on the data bus.  The transfer to the file will have to pause while other threads/tasks are using the data bus.  So, if you can, block all tasks, then transfer your data. :-)

I've written programs that copy from slow memory to fast memory, then transferred from fast memory to the hard drive.  That was also using interrupts (threads).

**Summary**
Fast writing to a file involves:

1. Keep the data streaming; minimize the pauses.
2. Write in binary mode (no translations, please).
3. Write in blocks (format into memory as necessary before writing the block).
4. Maximize the data in a transaction.
5. Use separate writing thread, if you want other tasks running "concurrently".
6. The hard drive is a serial device, not parallel.  Bits are written to the platters in a serial stream.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'hardware  assist', what do you mean with it and how could I implement it?

Comment: There are devices, called DMA (Direct Memory Access) that are designed to move data from memory to other places.  They can be independent or part of a larger hardware device.  USB devices have capability of moving data from memory through the USB port.  There may be something on a PC's motherboard that moves data from memory through the SATA channel to the hard drive.  Basically, these hardware devices operate in the *background*, allowing the CPU to perform other tasks during the data transfer.

Comment: patters?  Poor SSDs.  Also much modern io is async without threads.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont:  Threads are still used, especially in GUI applications.  You don't want a GUI application to freeze while data is written to a hard drive.